# What story had paper clips grow up to be coat hangers?

Tags: story-identification

I read it in an anthology about thirty years ago...  It had a creepy ending which I won't spoil.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Perhaps it was [*"Or All the Seas with Oysters"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Or_All_the_Seas_with_Oysters) by [Avram Davidson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avram_Davidson). A brief review can be found [here](http://das-ubernerd.blogspot.com/2007/12/reviews-or-all-seas-with-oysters-big.html).

Comment: Yup. The other, related theme of the story (and the inspiration for the story) is an observation that bicycles come in male and female kinds.